# How to solve: T(n)=a*T(n/4) + n^2/log n + n^2

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, recurrence

I'm trying to solve the recurrence equation of a **divide and conquer algorithm** knowing that the time required to decompose the copy into sub copies is in O(n^2/log n) and the time required for recombination is in O (n^2) .the number of sub-examples is **a** of size **n/4** which makes **T(n)=a*T(n/4) + n^2/log n + n^2**
so how to find the recurrence equation expressing the execution time T(n) in a function of the size **n** of the copy

thanks a lot

Comment: This sounds like a pure math question, not a programming question, no?

Comment: yes it sounds like a math question but this  equation expressing the execution time of an recurrent algorithm

Comment: It is indeed off-topic on this site. See Mathematics.

Comment: Looks like a prime example of an application of the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)).

Comment: thanks Neil it is very interst Link but f(n)=n^2+n^2/logn and this case is not deal by the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms))